# How can you solve the mysql connection error with logstash?

Tags: mysql, logstash

How can you solve the mysql connection error with logstash?

I tried all the information in Google.

However, it continues to fail, leaving questions in the stack overflow.

Please help me.

file name : mysql.conf (logstash file have the same route)

```
input {
    jdbc {
        clean_run => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\ElasticSearch\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobschema", "root","1234"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select jobid, jobname, executiontime, jobstatus from logstashplugin WHERE jobid > :sql_last_value"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => "jobid"
    }
}
output{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstashmysql"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Wrt.png)

---

Mysql - DB
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ96q.png)

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| commerce           |
| information_schema |
| jobschema          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| world              |
+--------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use jobschema;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_jobschema |
+---------------------+
| logplugin           |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from logplugin;
+-------+---------+---------------+-----------+
| jobid | jobname | executiontime | jobstatus |
+-------+---------+---------------+-----------+
|     1 | job1    |            10 | Completed |
|     2 | job2    |            15 | Failed    |
|     3 | job3    |            10 | Failed    |
|     4 | job4    |            30 | Failed    |
|     5 | job5    |            10 | Failed    |
|     6 | job6    |            15 | Failed    |
|     7 | job7    |            15 | Completed |
+-------+---------+---------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

logstash & db connection error file image

```
[2021-03-23T11:39:41,142][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"{\", \"}\" at line 6, column 74 (byte 282) after input {\n    jdbc {\n        clean_run => true\n        jdbc_driver_library => \"C:\\ElasticSearch\\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23\\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar\"\n        jdbc_driver_class => \"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\"\n        jdbc_connection_string => \"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobschema\"", :backtrace=>["C:/ElasticSearch/logstash-7.11.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "C:/ElasticSearch/logstash-7.11.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in `initialize'", "C:/ElasticSearch/logstash-7.11.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "C:/ElasticSearch/logstash-7.11.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:371:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2021-03-23T11:39:41,614][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-03-23T11:39:46,677][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-03-23T11:39:46,693][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.ElasticSearch.logstash_minus_7_dot_11_dot_2.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(C:\ElasticSearch\logstash-7.11.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWD9f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error message then you will see that it says

```
:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"{\", \"}\" at line 6, column 74 (byte 282) after 
input {\n    
    jdbc {\n        
    clean_run => true\n        
    jdbc_driver_library => \"C:\\ElasticSearch\\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23\\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar\"\n
    jdbc_driver_class => \"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\"\n
    jdbc_connection_string => \"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobschema\""
```

what your configuration shows is

```
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobschema", "root","1234"
```

I think what you meant was

```
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobschema"
jdbc_user => "root"
jdbc_password => "1234"
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your answer.

As you said, when I added the jdbc_password, the error phrase mentioned earlier disappeared.

However, another error phrase occurred.

Comment: [2021-03-23T13:45:00,158][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][71eb6bc08312e96b896722752853574a0dcf909e9c674c234f7f80c3e7fa7889] Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'jobschema.logstashplugin' doesn't exist: select jobid, jobname, executiontime, jobstatus from logstashplugin WHERE jobid > 0
[2021-03-23T13:45:00,162][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][71eb6bc08312e96b896722752853574a0dcf909e9c674c234f7f80c3e7fa7889] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'jobschema.logstashplugin' doesn't exist"}

Comment: Your 'showtables' output shows a table call logplugin, not logstashplugin.